# References for Glashow-Weinberg-Salam model

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model, higgs, electroweak

I am looking for reference recommendations on the Glashow-Weinberg-Salam theory of electroweak symmetry breaking. In particular, I am looking for a discussion of the $SU(2)\times U(1)$ gauge symmetry "breaking" and its connection to the Higgs phenomenon. I am familiar with the discussions in [Ryder's Quantum Field Theory](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantum-field-theory/7BBD6627FB00DDAF54275CF893AFC9FB) and [Halzen & Martin's Quark and Leptons](https://ajbell.web.cern.ch/Documents/eBooks/Quarks%20&%20Leptons.pdf), but I am looking for more detailed references (at the advanced grad student level) on this matter that go into detail concerning the calculations. Any books, online reviews, or articles would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly In general, I'm looking for more details on the Higgs mechanism itself in the context of SU(2)xU(1) symmetry breaking

Comment: Maybe cheng&li gauge theory of elementary particle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question  is actually unclear, as it instantly multiplexes into four quite   different questions, which I will not spend time to parse. Before any discursive bloviations I'll send you to

- a [classic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521476526),  ISBN-13: 978-0521476522, *Dynamics of the Standard Model*  by 
  J  Donoghue, E  Golowich, B  Holstein, a bare minimum for particle theorists.

Now for the bloviation: A better alternative  to your "pragmatic" references for pro-forma introductions include

- [M Schwartz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107034736) ,  ISBN-13: 978-1107034730 , *Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model*
- [T P Cheng & L L Li](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198519613) , ISBN-13: 978-0198519614 , *Gauge Theory of elementary particle physics*
- [JB Zuber & C Itzykson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486445682) ,  ISBN-13: 978-0486445687 , *Quantum Field Theory*
- [TD Lee](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3718600331),  ISBN-13: 978-3718600335 , *Particle Physics and Introduction to Field Theory*
- [E Abers & B Lee 1973](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(73)90027-6)    "Gauge theories" *Physics Reports, 9(1), pp.1-2*

and, literally, dozens of equivalents. They've done yeoman's duty in educating thousands.  On the off chance you are really asking about radiative corrections, a starting point might be

- [W Hollik 1990](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(73)90027-6) Hollik, Wolfgang FL. "Radiative Corrections in the Standard Model and Their Rǒle for Precision Tests of the Electroweak Theory." *Fortschritte der Physik/Progress of Physics 38, no. 3 (1990): 165-260*